# How to find host or public IP from RDP session to an Azure SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure

Basically, I need the host and port that i need to use to integrate my Azure SQL server with Zappier. Currently, we can only access the server through and RDP and not through Azure Portal.

Comment: Do you really mean Azure SQL, or do you mean a VM running in Azure with SQL installed? You can't RDP to Azure SQL

Comment: A VM running in Azure, because I can RDP to it.

Comment: Any more question?

Answer (score 0):

You can just RDP to the VM and run the PowerShell command `Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json` without installing Azure PowerShell. Then you can get the VM public IP.

**Update**

Also, you can use Azure Instance Metadata Service to get the VM public IP like this:

```
$metadataResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/network?api-version=2018-02-01" -H @{"Metadata"="true"} -UseBasicParsing
$metadata = ConvertFrom-Json ($metadataResponse.Content)
$metadata.interface[0].ipv4.ipAddress
```

Or just one PowerShell command like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/network/interface/0/ipv4/ipAddress?api-version=2018-02-01" -H @{"Metadata"="true"} -UseBasicParsing
```

For more details, see [Retrieving metadata in Windows Virtual Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service#retrieving-metadata-in-windows-virtual-machine).